# launching renv::activate() with RMarkdown causes R to crash

Tags: r, linux, r-markdown, renv

I have a r-markdown chunk with this command line:

`renv::activate(file.path(proj_root, "my_folder"))`

When I run this line alone in the console or with `ctrl`+`enter`, it works perfectly.

But when I try the `Run current chunk` or `Run all chunks above` buttons, R session fails (I do not have more precise error message).

Here are my R specifs:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

Last time, I changed Ubuntu's system language from French to English, can it have something to do ?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: And changing the language back to French doesn’t cause a R crash?

Comment: No it didn't :(. But it maybe it has nothing to do.